# Dynamic API URL

Tags: angular

This is how my *proxyconfig.json* looks like:

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:80",
    "pathRewrite": {
      "^/api": ""
    },
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

I don't want to change the value of `target` evertime when I deploy. Is there a way I could use http://localhost:80 for the development mode and http://example.com for the production mode?

Comment: You can use environment.ts for development mode and environment,prod.ts for production mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the environment as a different mode please use the below code in angular.json file.

```
"configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
"dev": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev.ts"
                }
              ],
}
```

I just put a sample code. You can set options more manually.

Answer (score 0):

`proxy.config.json` has effect on your local Angular dev server only - it has no impact on the production build.

The above is true as long as you're not using that same development server on production (which is not recommended by the way).

However, if that's the case, you should be able to create a separate `proxy.config.prod.json` and use `fileReplacements` section of `angular.json`, just like [Rushi Patel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9308080/rushi-patel) mentioned in the answer above.